# pin some of user selected rows at the top of a list in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using a listview that contains a costumized rows. I want to select some of them to stay at the top of my list
( something like pining chats in telegram).
How to implement this feature?

Comment: You can check `sliver_tools`, it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this package solves your case: https://pub.dev/packages/pinnable_listview

Comment: I think this one only supports one of tiles but I need multiple tiles to be pinned